# Poor upload speed in KVM guest with virtio eth driver in OpenStack on 3.14

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openstack

After upgrading an OpenStack compute node to the 3.14 kernel, I am getting poor upload speed from all KVM guests when using virtio ethernet driver. Download speeds are unaffected and HTTP download stays at a constant 50 MB/s, however uploads start at 2 MB/s and drop down to kilobits per second (on a 1 gbps network). This includes both TX out of the network and TX between virtual machines.

Setup:

- OpenStack Icehouse with neutron networking
- GRE tunneled network under ml2 plugin via openvswitch
- GRO is disabled on all physical interfaces, which are on igb 2.0.5 driver
- data interfaces are connected via 1gbit ports/switch
- single dedicated network node with several compute nodes
- all servers running 14.04 (also tried 14.10 on one compute node but issue persists)

Once driver is switched to e1000, the network performance returns to expected speed (but e1000 yields worse performance than virtio; around 16 MB/s upload). Additionally, on another node still running 3.13 kernel, the upload speed is > 50 MB/s (and transfer from VM on 3.13 node to VM on 3.14 node is fine, while transfer in opposite direction has this choppy upload issue).

In SSH on the guest, simply running cat on a 2000-line file shows the issue, with freezes every 2 seconds. On normal guest it prints within half a second.

Note that only compute node is affected by this issue -- with two compute nodes in the same cluster, one node running 3.13 and the other running 3.14, and neutron network node running something else (shouldn't matter but I think it's on 3.16 at the moment), the 3.13 is still fine while guests on 3.14 node have the problem.

I noticed bug report in https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74851. However

- a) it's my understanding that IP forwarding is not needed on compute node (after disabling it via "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" the guest network still runs) and
- b) after upgrading to newest 3.14, newest 3.15, and newest 3.16 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ the issue persists.

Comment: If 3.13 is ok but 3.14 is bad, and e1000 is ok but virtio is bad, then this is probably a bug in 3.14 networking/virtio. What you need to do is compile a kernel from the latest git tip, test it, if the bug still exists then git bisect to find the commit that introduced the bug, and then report the bug to the relevant kernel developer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this wasn't actually kernel related, but instead for some reason upgrading to the 3.14 mainline kernel caused TSO to be enabled on the bridge, tap, and other interfaces that OpenStack automatically create.

After running `ethtool -K [interface] gro off tso off` on each qbr, qvb, qvo, and tap interface, virtio driver returns to good performance.

Since I need 3.14 for some other changes related to bcache, I ended up patching OpenStack nova in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/network/linux_net.py` to run the ethtool command (via utils.execute with run_as_root=True) each time one of these interfaces is created. So far it seems to be working.